# Is there any python library for converting text into words?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am having  a dataframe which has column name called description. Please see the sample description

This is my sample observation:

[image]

It has numbers on the description. And I need to convert the numbers into text and need output as follow

[image]

From the above, I wanted to convert the numbers into words for my NLP process. Is there any library in converting numbers into words? I have 50000 observations

Please advise.

Comment: [num2word](https://pypi.org/project/num2word/) or [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/).

Comment: @HampusLarsson Thanks. I tried with this code and it's coming error. My data in pandas dataframe. num2words(df2['cleaned_desc']) --> df2 is my dataframe name and cleaned_Desc is my column name. It has 50000 observations. can you advise?

Comment: Please update the question with examples of the dataframe, and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will preface this answer saying that I think there definitely is a more stable built-in solution for this in Pandas itself.

With that said, here is a solution using the [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) package:

```
import num2words
import random
import re
import pandas as pd

def randomSentence(wordList):
    """Uses wordList to create a sentance with random-numbers strewn in."""
    words = [random.choice(wordList) for i in range(3)]
    for i in range(random.randint(1,4)):
        words.append(round(random.uniform(0, 10), 2))
    random.shuffle(words)
    return " ".join(str(i) for i in words)

def transInt(string):
    """checks if there is a '.' in the given number, and returns the translation."""
    if "." in string:
        return num2words.num2words(float(string))
    return num2words.num2words(int(string))

def replaceInt(string):
    """Replaces integers and floats with a translated string using the function transInt """
    return re.sub(r"(\d+\.*\d*)", lambda x: transInt(x.group()), string)

# Lorem ipsum that is used as a wordlist to create sentences.
x = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
       Nam sit amet nunc sollicitudin, viverra dolor ut, feugiat tellus.
       Curabitur erat arcu, viverra vitae augue sed, maximus vestibulum ante."""
x = [i.strip(",.") for i in x.split()]

# Creating a list of random sentences, with numbers strewn in
sentences = [randomSentence(x) for i in range(2)]

# Creating a df with each of the sentences.
df = pd.DataFrame(sentences, columns=["Sentence"])

# Adds a new column 'Translated' to the dataframe with the numbers translated.
df["Translated"] = df.Sentence.apply(replaceInt)
for i in df.iterrows():
    _, data = i
    print(f'Original: {data.Sentence}')
    print(f'Translated: {data.Translated}')
    print("-"*20)
```

Because you didn't provide easily copy/paste versions of your `DataFrame`, I created a function to return a random sentence to work with.

Sample output:

```
Original: arcu 7.48 ut 1.53 8.72 sit 7.13
Translated: arcu seven point four eight ut one point five three eight point seven two sit seven point one three
--------------------
Original: elit 3.55 amet 7.88 tellus
Translated: elit three point five five amet seven point eight eight tellus
--------------------
```